# Is 256MB RAM enough for a VPS server to run some Drupal-based websites with e-shop module?

Tags: performance, vps, memory, drupal

Is 256MB RAM enough for a VPS server to run some Drupal-based websites with e-shop module ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to "run" nearly anything in the LAMP world.

It is not enough to handle more than a certain amount of load. How much depends on the app, and could be anything from 1 to tens of concurrent users.

Comment: And of course, the OP would have to benchmark it himself to find out what those specifics are! :)

Answer (score 0):

Good enough to start with.  Surely your VPS vendor will be able to upgrade your VPS if you find you need more - all you need to do then is reboot to get the extra memory.

Answer (score -1):

You can probably install it, but I would recommend against using so little.  Unless of course you don't have much content and/or very few views.  I don't have hard numbers for you, but you may have to resort to performance testing to determine your needs.

Comment: How few is very few views? Some people might consider 10,000 very few. For many *very* few is like 5... Static content isn't very memory hungry.  Dynamic content might be, but again depends on number of visitors.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but this is fundamentally the same answer as Luke404's answer...  I added a note that performance testing would help evaluate need.